# LINQ how to Filter the data based on the value of the properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xamarin

i have a problem with filtering data in LINQ , here is my Model :

```
 public class CoursePlan
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Semester { get; set; }
        public string ModuleCode { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public string Credits { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string ModuleStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

and here is my data `Json`

[image]

the problem here some modules having same `OrderNumber` which mean they are optional , student must study one of them  and if student already study one of them , i should ignore other modules in same order number.

in other way to describe the question

i want to return a list of CoursePlan  and on this list if there is two items having same `OrderNumber` check the `ModuleStatus` for each one of them and if any one is `Completed` remove other modules on that order otherwise return them all .

here is my code

```
var coursePlanList = await _sqLiteAsyncConnection.Table<CoursePlan>().ToListAsync();
var groupedData = coursePlanList.OrderBy(e => e.Semester)
    .GroupBy(e => e.OrderNumber)
    .Select(e => new ObservableGroupCollection<string, CoursePlan>(e))
    .ToList();
```

for now im solving this by this algorithm and not sure if it's the best

```
    var coursePlanList = await _sqLiteAsyncConnection.Table<CoursePlan>().ToListAsync();

    List<CoursePlan> finalList = new List<CoursePlan>();

    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var itemPlan in coursePlanList)
    {
        if (counter > 0 && counter < coursePlanList.Count)
            if (itemPlan.OrderNumber == coursePlanList[counter - 1].OrderNumber)
            {
                if (itemPlan.ModuleStatus == "Completed")
                {
                    finalList.RemoveAll(a => a.OrderNumber == itemPlan.OrderNumber);
                    finalList.Add(itemPlan);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(itemPlan.ModuleName + "With -->" + coursePlanList[counter - 1].ModuleName);
            }

            else
                finalList.Add(itemPlan);

        counter++;
    }

    var groupedData = finalList.OrderBy(e => e.ModuleStatus)
        .ThenBy(e => e.Semester)
        .GroupBy(e => e.Semester)
        .Select(e => e)
        .ToList();

    CoursePlanViewList.BindingContext = new ObservableCollection<IGrouping<string, CoursePlan>>(groupedData);
```

***Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated***

Comment: I suspect something this complex can't be done with LINQ alone, or at least not in a single query.  But some LINQ expert may prove me wrong.

Comment: i was thinking about breaking the list into two list but that will affect the processing speed and also not working as i expect , BTW will see other expert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase your requirement: you want to show all plans per `OrderNumber` that meet the condition: none of the plans in their group should be "Completed" or the plans themselves should be "Completed". All this grouped by `Semester`:

```
var plansQuery = 
from p in _sqLiteAsyncConnection.Table<CoursePlan>()
group p by p.Semester into sem
select new
{
    PlansInSemester = 
        from p in sem
        group p by p.OrderNumber into gp
        select new
        {
            PlansInOrderNumber =
                gp.Where(p => !gp.Any(p1 => p1.ModuleStatus == "Completed")
                           || p.ModuleStatus == "Completed")
        }
};
```

This gives you an `IQueryable` that produces the course plans you want to select, but grouped in two levels, so the final result is obtained by flattening the query twice:

```
var coursePlanList = await plansQuery
    .SelectMany(x => x.PlansInSemester
        .SelectMany(y => y.PlansInOrderNumber)).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: each module in each semester have unique orderNumber  if 2 module having same OrderNumber , this mean one of them should be Completed  , if yes there is two or three module having same order and one of them Status Completed  then ignore other module on that order and return the Completed one , otherwise if all three having same order and no one of them is completed , then return them all , hopefully you get what i mean

Comment: Doesn't this query give the expected output? I think I follow you, but to my understanding the query does exactly what you want.

Comment: I modfy my question with my  basic solution maybe you will understand my requirements from my solution   I have tried your query, 1 : its returning semester only and plan object , I modifiy it but not getting expected values, if you could make the query return entire properties,

Comment: Did you try my query? I think you shouldn't add and remove but just query what you need from the original collection. It would help to see sample data and expected output.

Comment: Yes sir I’ve tried it , look at my question there is expected output, im returning CoursePlan model after filtering, can you give example how to execute your query? It’s not returning CoursePlan model , i want to return all the collection but if there is more than one module having same order number value and one of them is completed , ignore none complete and return the completed one , if all modules having same order and none of them is completed then return them all, this doesn’t mean ignore other data which have unique order number . Thanks for understanding

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to make the query return `CoursePlan` entities.

Comment: it's working by using foreach , but not able to change it to IGrouping like 

new ObservableCollection<IGrouping<string, CoursePlan>>(coursePlanList ); will throw error , BTW thanks a lot for help sound great